# tkinter countdown timer using after does not allow for multiple consecutive uses

Tags: python, tkinter, timer

I have written a basic countdown timer in tkinter. The countdown timer works correctly the first time it is used but if I enter a second time to countdown, the timer counts down at a pace that is twice that of the previous countdown and if I use it a third time then the countdown pace doubles again and so on and so on.

I specify the countdown interval to be 1000 ms in the self.after() command but it appears as though that value gets halved every time a new countdown time is entered. It appears as though the wait time gets halved on each consecutive use. If I close the countdown widget and re-open it the process repeats starting with the correct time and then halving the time on each consecutive use.

The following is simplified code of my full application which demonstrates the issue. The time is manually entered in seconds in the Text box just to the right of the words 'Seconds To Countdown' and the Start Countdown button is pressed to begin the countdown. Repeating this process demonstrates the issue.

I thought perhaps that including an update_idletasks command would address the problem but it doesn't.

```
from tkinter import *

class timerTestGui(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.makeWidgets()

    def initiateCountdown(self):
        time = self.text_timer.get("1.0", END).strip()
        time = int(time)
        #self.update_idletasks()
        self.countdown(time)

    def countdown(self, remaining=None):
        if remaining is not None:
            self.remaining = remaining
        self.label_countdown.configure(text=self.remaining)
        self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
        self.after(1000,self.countdown)

    def makeWidgets(self):
        self.label_current_timer = Label(self,text='Seconds To Countdown')
        self.label_current_timer.grid(row=0,column=2)
        self.text_timer = Text(self, relief=SUNKEN, height=1, width=10)
        self.text_timer.tag_configure("center", justify='center')
        self.text_timer.grid(row=0,column=3)
        self.label_countdown = Label(self, text='')
        self.label_countdown.grid(row=0,column=4)
        self.button_session_start = Button(self, text='Start\nCountdown', command=self.initiateCountdown)
        self.button_session_start.grid(row=0,column=5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Countdown Timer')
    app = timerTestGui(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

If anybody has any ideas on how to get the countdown timer to work correctly on each consecutive use I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Your title includes the word "threading" but your code doesn't use threads.

Comment: It's my understanding that the self.after() command is a threading command.

Comment: No, `after()` does not create threads. It simply adds something to the internal event queue used by tkinter. Tkinter is single threaded.

Comment: My mistake, I just looked it up and see that this is classified as a time tool. I'd still like to solve the issue however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you never stop the old timer before creating a new timer. The first time you create the timer, you run a function every second. The next time you create a timer, the old function is still running, but you've now added a second function that is called every second. The next time you add a third, and so on. So, if you hit the button 10 times, you end up updating your counter 10 times a second.

Assuming you want only a single instance running, you need to stop the old `after` command before starting a new one. `after` returns an id that you can use for this purpose.

First, initialize a variable you can use to store the id of the current `after` command:

```
class timerTestGui(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
        self.after_id = None
        ...
```

Next, make sure that whenever you call `after`, you save the returned id:

```
def countdown(self, remaining=None):
    ...
    self.after_id = self.after(1000,self.countdown)
```

Finally, when creating a new timer, kill the old one first:

```
def initiateCountdown(self):
    ...
    if self.after_id is not None:
        self.after_cancel(self.after_id)
    self.countdown(time)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Your solution works perfectly. I got caught up in thinking this was some type of threading issue which clearly was a mistake on my part. Thanks again.